# $\int_{0}^{6} x^{\{x\}} d x $ where {} in the G.I.F

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, indefinite-integrals, special-functions

An integral question from the NSEA-2018(question 70 in [this](https://www.resonance.ac.in/answer-key-solutions/ISO/2018-19/Stage-1/Solution/NSEA-Code-A421-v2.pdf) solutions booklet) Paper.

Q.Find the integer closest to the integral $$
\int_{0}^{6} x^{\{\sqrt{x}\}} d x
$$
, where {x} denotes the largest integer not exceeding x.* ***Corrected a latex error here*** *

The question is filled with strangeness as they've used mod(|x|) in the Integral and not [x]but have described {x} and not [x]as the G.I.F.) * ***Corrected a mistake originally added here-ignore this*** *.
My thoughts:-
1. An indefinite integral of $x^{x}$ is unknown. But not sure about definite.

2. I tried substitutions and King's property but failed to reach anywhere meaningful.
3. Unsure on how to tackle a fractional part in the power.

Comment: "impossible (in an indefinite state)": what ??

Comment: You should avoid MathJax *only* titles.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Sorry. Read point 1.

Comment: @ShreyasJV: hiding text makes my comment incomprehensible.

Comment: Question $70$ in the pdf you linked to is not the same.

Comment: @bjorn93 Yes it is. I've made the correction they've stated on bold.

Comment: @ShreyasJV no, the exponent there has a square root

Comment: Have you considered what the function looks like? The integrand is piecewise defined so just split the integral into pieces.

Comment: It's unclear, to me at least, exactly what your question is. You seem to recognize that there are mistakes in the way the problem is posed in the site you linked to, but it's not clear (again, to me) if you understand what problem the site *meant* to pose, namely to compute closest integer to $$\int_0^6x^{\lfloor\sqrt x\rfloor}dx$$ where $\lfloor\cdot\rfloor$ is the greatest integer (aka "floor") function. Are you simply asking how to compute that (correctly stated) integral?

Comment: Note, the linked site's solution is basically correct, except for a typo: they have a $15^2$ where they should have a $152$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question is crippled with mistakes.

If first shows the exponent $|\sqrt x|$, where the absolute value is useless. Then if defines $\{x\}$ though this is not used, and assigns it the meaning of the *floor* function !?

Finally the solution is given for

$$\int_0^6 x^{\lfloor\sqrt x\rfloor}dx$$ by decomposing the range, and the computation is wrong (but the final answer is right)

---

In your question, you dropped the square root and worsened the ambiguity.

---

$$\int_1^6 x^{\lfloor\sqrt x\rfloor}dx=\int_0^1dx+\int_1^4x\,dx+\int_4^6x^2\,dx=1+\frac{4^2-1}2+\frac{6^3-4^2}3=59.16\cdots.$$

Comment: I believe the wrong computation you allude to is a typo: a $15^2$ that should be simply a $152$.

Comment: @BarryCipra: yep.

Answer (score 2):

Here $[.]$ is GIF.
$$\int_{0}^{6} x^{[x]} dx==\int_{0}^{1} x^0 dx+ \int_{1}^{2} x^1 dx+\int_{2}^{3} x^2 dx+\int_{3}^{4} x^3 dx.+\int_{4}^{5} x^4 dx....+\int_{5}^{6} x^5 dx=\frac{338677}{60} $$